# How do I add default horizontal padding values to Scaffold's PaddingValues?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I got this simple composable (shorterned):

```
Scaffold(topBar = {
    TopAppBar(title = { Text("...") })
}) { paddingValues ->
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues = paddingValues)) {
        // Some view
    }
}
```

This results in the following view:

[image]

I am curious if there is a way to provide default leading and trailing padding values that I receive from the `Scaffold`'s closure. Now the text and switch takes up all the width, I don't want that. Of course, this is a quick solution:

`.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)`

But adding that to every composable that uses a `Scaffold` looks weird to me. Is there an easier solution?

Comment: `Scaffold` calculates those padding values internally, so there's not much you can do about it. Making a wrapper `Composable` like @J.K suggests seems like the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a Box() around your content for the sole purpose of applying the Scaffold Padding, then that would allow you to continue to use normal padding for your own content.

```
 @Composable  
    fun PaddingTest() {
            Scaffold(
                topBar = {
                    TopAppBar(
                        title = { Text("TopAppBar Here") }
                    )
                }
            ) { scaffoldPadding ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(scaffoldPadding)
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(
                                top = 20.dp, bottom = 300.dp,
                                start = 60.dp, end = 10.dp
                            )
                            .background(Color.LightGray),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    ) {
                        Text("my weird padding")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: sample padding]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure about my answer but let's review this.
How about creating a custom wrapper name like `View`

```
@Composable
fun View(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = someVerticalPad, horizontal = someHorizontalPad)) {
        content()
    }
}
```

then

```
Scaffold(topBar = {
                    TopAppBar(title = { Text("...") })
                }) {
                    MainApp {
                        Text(text = ".........")
                    }
                }
```

`paddingValues` coming from scaffold is zero for both horizontal and vertical values. try a quick debug you will get to know.